# Use of Verbose in a cron job

Tags: cron, rsync, options

I'm busy setting up a back-up script to run on my Pi using `rsync`.

I see that a number of people use the `-v` option in their cron jobs. **Why?** It's going to be run as root, and not in a terminal where someone will see it.

I understand that maybe if something happens you can `tail /var/logs/syslog`, but the chance of that happening is negligible.

As I'm running the backup between 2 external hard drives on the same system, I can see the benefit of using `-za`. The `-z` for compression because why not, the CPU is barely taxed at the best of times. The `-a` to preserve permissions, time-stamps, symlinks and owners and groups and to make it recursive.

I might remove the `-z` and replace it with `-W` to write whole files in stead of blocks, but I don't want it to run for too many hours.

Is there a way to output any encountered errors to an error log file? In that case, the `-v` option might make sense - unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: The `-z` option of `rsync` is effective only for network transfers, so it is ignored when both source and destinations are on the same machine.

Comment: Good to know. I'm using it to back up partitions on the same computer. so it's pointless there. However, I am planning on using it to  replicate to a separate network device at some point in the future, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: For backups you can consider `rdiff-backup` which actually backs up the data (stores compressed binary differences between actual and old files), not just copies them. It is based on `rsync`.

Comment: @Marki555 Thanks for the extra info. I've done a bit of reading up on it. I don't really need incremental backups, only a single back-up if my primary HDD fails. One comparative review on `rsync` vs `rdiff-backup` indicates that generating those SHA-1 hashes uses quite a bit of CPU. (all the cores on an core-i7 CPU). As I'm running it on a RPI2, I don't really want to overtax it too much. So I think I'll stick with rsync for now. I appreciate your feedback though, and I'm sure that someone will find it useful. (once again, I'd +1 if I could).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `cron` sends the output of the jobs it runs to the relevant user; so `-v` is useful there because you get an email with the full output of the `rsync` command. On a correctly-configured system, even mail to `root` goes to the appropriate user.

For this to work you need mail to be setup appropriately on the system running `cron`; that used to be common on Unix-type systems, not so much nowadays... `cron` uses `sendmail` by default to send email; this can be overridden with the `-m` option to `crond`. Alternatively, you can configure `crond` to log job output using `syslog`, with the `-s` option.

You can also redirect individual `cron` jobs' output using shell redirection, so `> somelog.log 2> errorlog.log` would log standard output to `somelog.log`, and standard error to `errorlog.log` (you can of course add paths).

Comment: Usually I just redirect stdout to a logfile (so I can look later) and leave stderr unredirected, so when error occurs I receive an email from cron.

Comment: @Marki555 yup, that works well; I tend to use [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)' `chronic` (but that doesn't leave any trace at all when everything appears to go well).

Comment: Very cool! love the moreutils! going to be re-doing a lot of things with that `chronic` now!

Would +1 if i could on that! Thanks!